# Why do Hilbert logic systems use the axioms that they do?

Tags: logic, definition, propositional-calculus, axioms

For example in a Hilbert system for propositional logic, one sample system uses modus ponens along with three axioms:

I. $A \to (B \to A)$

II. $(A \to (B \to C)) \to ((A \to B) \to (A \to C))$

III. $(\lnot B \to \lnot A) \to (A \to B)$

How did Hilbert come up with these axioms as enough to represent an entire logic system?

Is it mostly trial and error to come up with a set of axioms or is there a method to the madness?

Comment: One method is to look at what you want to do with the axioms. For example, if we  have a proof that some larger set of axioms is complete, we can look at exactly which axioms are used in that proof, and make a smaller complete set of axioms by only keeping the ones that we actually needed.  But I don't know how this particular set of axioms was created.

Comment: Hilbert didn't come up with this axiom set.  The axiom set comes from Lukasiewicz and used his notation.

Comment: Some of the axiom sets that get used come from Lukasiewicz.  There exist methods to derive more axiom sets, which I outlined here: https://dougspoonwood.blogspot.com/2014/11/axiomatic-proofs-which-prove.html  Basically you take two known axiom sets and use one to derive the other.  Then you look at the last few steps and replace one of the derived formulas with it's parents in the proof.  Though, I don't think Lukasiewicz found that axiom set that way.

Comment: As for Lukasiewicz's thinking, there's the possibility that his thinking might not be recoverable, since his method might have existed in his notes which got burned in the bombing of Warsaw.

Comment: The first two are very useful because they alone allow us to prove the Deduction Theorem. The third one is (one of many possible way) of introducing negation and classical logic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83410/discussion-between-peter-and-carl-mummert).

Comment: Yes, chat is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How this set of axioms was originally found was likely a mixture of trial and error, adapting earlier work, and optimizing for the minimal number of axioms. Connections to combinatory logic that I touch on below were probably also a factor.

For a (probably) ahistorical account, let me begin by slightly rewriting the first two axioms:

$A\to(\Gamma\to A)$

$(\Gamma\to(A\to B))\to(\Gamma\to A)\to(\Gamma\to B)$

If we scratch out the $\Gamma$s, we get $A\to A$ and $(A\to B)\to(A\to B)$ (the latter can be thought of as a curried form of $(A\to B)\land A \to B$). We can think of these as internalizations of the Identity and Cut rules: $$\dfrac{}{A\vdash A}\qquad \dfrac{A\vdash B\qquad \vdash A}{\vdash B}$$ Adding the $\Gamma$s back gives us internalizations of the above rules with contexts, i.e. the rules: $$\dfrac{}{\Gamma,A\vdash A}\qquad \dfrac{\Gamma,A\vdash B\qquad \Gamma\vdash A}{\Gamma\vdash B}$$

The upshot is that we can encode hypothetical reasoning by encoding $\Gamma\vdash A$ as $\Gamma\to A$ and then manipulating these with the internal identity and cut "rules". Sure enough, axioms I and II are what is necessary to prove the Deduction Theorem. As a proof relevant perspective on this, axioms I and II correspond to $K$ and $S$ of [combinatory logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Completeness_of_the_S-K_basis) and the Deduction Theorem corresponds to bracket abstraction.

If we stop here, we have positive implicational logic. If we continue on and keep using our idea of encoding hypothetical reasoning $\Gamma\vdash A$ as $\Gamma\to A$, then we should look at the rules for $\neg$. In the sequent calculus they are: $$\dfrac{\Gamma,\neg A\vdash\Delta}{\Gamma\vdash A,\Delta}\qquad\dfrac{\Gamma\vdash\neg A,\Delta}{\Gamma,A\vdash\Delta}$$ Of course, using both of these rules gives: $$\dfrac{\Gamma,\neg B\vdash\neg A,\Delta}{\Gamma,A\vdash B,\Delta}$$ This rule has the benefit of not changing the number of conclusions. We can roughly get the original rules by choosing $A$ to be something that's provable or $B$ something that is refutable.

The first rule for $\neg$ suggests that we can represent the extra conclusions, $\Delta$, via extra negated assumptions in $\Gamma$. The third axiom then doesn't need to deal with the assumptions, since the Deduction Theorem based on the other two axioms means we can add them when we want. The handwaving I'm doing here is whether a rule like $\dfrac{\Gamma,\neg B\vdash\neg A}{\Gamma,A\vdash B}$ is strong enough *as the only rule for negation* to derive all classical results (in a context where we also have rules for implication). We could, for example, take $\neg\neg A\to A$ as an axiom instead but this turns out to be too weak on its own. That this might be the case, you could see by viewing it as an encoding of a rule as we've been doing. That (encoded) rule doesn't give us any way of dealing with *singly* negated hypotheses or (single) negations in conclusions.

In general, a lot of axioms in Hilbert style systems can be understood as viewing them as encodings of rules. As an example, one axiom for $\lor$ is $(A\to C)\to(B\to C)\to (A\lor B \to C)$ which we can view as an encoding of the rule $\dfrac{A\vdash C\qquad B\vdash C}{A\lor B\vdash C}$. Of course, the encoding represents $\vdash$, meta-implication (i.e. the horizontal bar in rules), and $\to$ all as $\to$. For example, above I said the second axiom encoded the Cut rule, but I could just as well have said it encoded a modus-ponens-with-contexts rule.